# Gnome - windows always open top left

Tags: gnome, windows, gedit, compiz

I find this a highly annoying "feature" on a wide screen monitor that my mostly used apps - terminal and gedit always open directly under the top-left corner of my screen and I have to drag them to my eye position each and every-time.

I have tried installing the CompizConfig Settings Manager and using the feature to position windows centre, but this has had no effect - the force feature here isn't working for me either:

Window Management -> "place windows" -> Fixed Window Placement -> Windows with fixed positions
example: gedit 200 200 keep-in-work-area-to-yes

I can use e.g. gnome-terminal --geometry=140x50+50+50 for the terminal but this doesn't work for gedit.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, since GNOME v3.30 there is a visible option in [GNOME Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks), which makes it much easier to enable it:

[image: GNOME Tweaks with Windows->"Center New Windows" highlighted]

Just select "Center New Windows" under "Windows".

---

Actually I found a solution for GNOME without compiz.
You can either use

- [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/850/place-windows-in-center/) if you have gnome-shell < v3.14
- or open dconf and set `center-new-windows` in `org.gnome.mutter` to `true`:
  [image: dconf open with org.gnome.mutter -> center-new-windows]

Comment: Actually I opened a bug report to make this setting the default: gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/246 IMHO, everything else makes no sense. Feel free to upvote it. :)

Comment: BTW, in contrast to what i said, (that it's the default in Ubuntu now) this topic is not dead and still in discussion in [Fedora](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/should-gnome-center-new-windows-by-default-or-not/1413?u=rugk) & [Ubuntu](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/center-windows-by-default/10262?u=rugk).

Comment: Gnome Tweaks was the easiest option for me

Answer (score 1):

The Compiz “place windows” feature works for me. It won’t work if you just use `gedit`, though. Try `title=gedit`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works for me as expected with Compiz and the `Fixed Window Placement -> Windows with fixed positions` set to:

```
Positioned windows: class=Gedit
200 200
keep-in-work-area: no
```